# Using SSL with a Let'sEncrypt cert, using shared Dreamhost Apache server, for a React SecureServer with Ratchet

Tags: php, html, reactjs, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am currently getting an error:

```
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

when trying to connect to a secure React server. 

I am using a Dreamhost shared hosted server plan, my signed cert is provided by LetsEncrypt. I can access the raw text of the certificate, RSA private key, and intermediate certificate for my site via Dreamhost's web portal. I copied these into files in the same directory as the chat-server.php script, so my filetree looks like:

mydomain.com:

| chat.php

| bin:

| | chat-server.php

| | public.pem          //contains the certificate text copied from Dreamhost

| | key.pem             //contains the private key text copied from Dreamhost

...

with chat.php being a file to instantiate the websocket for the client.

Here's the chat-server.php:

```
<?php

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
    new \Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
        new \MyApp\Chat()
    )
);

$loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$certs = openssl_get_cert_locations();

$secure_websockets = new \React\Socket\Server('0.0.0.0:8080', $loop);
$secure_websockets = new \React\Socket\SecureServer($secure_websockets, $loop, [
    'local_cert' => "public.pem",
    'local_pk' => "key.pem"
]);

$secure_websockets_server = new \Ratchet\Server\IoServer($app, $secure_websockets, $loop);
$secure_websockets_server->run();
```

But I am getting the SSL version or cipher mismatch. What does my certificate file need to contain? Do I need to point 'local_cert' to another location on my server? Do I need my private key? I've tried including both the certificate and intermediate certificate in the public.pem file, different file extensions, different SSL context options, and nothing has worked.